# EditTexts in Gallery and focus issue

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

i am trying to add few EditText in a gallery view. i could manage the scrolling by overriding the onInterceptTouchEvent but i am facing issue in geting focus to the edit texts.

Most of the time even though the softkey board is visible, its not showing the typed text in the visible edit text in the screen.

I tried seting onclick listner for the edit text to set focus on the clicked view but still it doesn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this property,

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```